# Symfony: Load Extensioin without Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I have a Symfony 5.4 application. I have created a `sso_settings.yml` within my `config/packages/` folder.

There is no bundle structure, so I created a `DependencyInjection` Folder under my `src/` folder with the file `AppConfiguration.php` and the file `AppExtension.php`.

Because I have no bundle, I registered my Extension in my Kernel.php class with

```
protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        $container->registerExtension(new AppExtension());
    }
```

AppConfiguration.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);


namespace App\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class AppConfiguration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder('sso_settings');

        $treeBuilder->getRootNode()
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('siam_role_hierarchy')
                    ->useAttributeAsKey('id')
                    ->prototype('scalar')
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

AppExtension.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;

class AppExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new AppConfiguration();
        $processedConfig = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
            $container,
            new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../../config/packages')
        );
        $loader->load('sso_settings.yaml');
    }

    public function getAlias(): string
    {
        return 'sso_settings';
    }
}
```

The path to the `sso_settings.yaml` is correct.

But now I get this error:

```
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "sso_settings" (in "/var/www/app/src/DependencyInjection/../../config/packages/sso_settings.yaml"). Looked for namespace "sso_settings", found "none".
```

Can someone help me with this? I cannot find the issue.

Comment: It's been awhile but I think you need to use [Kernel::prepareContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64698404/how-to-load-a-custom-config-file-in-a-bundleless-application-with-treebuilder/64699601#64699601) to register your extension.  Easy enough to try.  And as pointed out in the linked answer there is really no point in doing what you are trying to do unless eventually you plan on moving the functionality to it's own bundle.

Comment: I also just noticed you have `$loader->load('sso_settings.yaml');` in your extension class.  That is a misunderstanding of how the config system works.  Your AppExtension::load method will be called with the contents of sso_settings.yaml passed as an argument.  If it all seems weird it's because it is.  The config system is based on bundle configuration, not application configuration.

Comment: have you found a solution? have exactly the same behaviour in symfony6.1

Answer (score 1):

I found a proper way to create a global app configuration. The following are
the classes and files required to make it work.

Create the extension class at `src/DependencyInjection/AppExtension.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension;

class AppExtension extends Extension
{
    public function getAlias(): string
    {
        return 'app';
    }

    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        /*
        $configs = [
            0 => [
               "hello_world" => "!"
            ]
        ]
        */
    }

    public function getConfiguration(array $config, ContainerBuilder $container): ConfigurationInterface
    {
        return new AppConfiguration();
    }
}
```

Create the related configuration class at `src/DependencyInjection/AppConfiguration.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class AppConfiguration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder(): TreeBuilder
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder('app');

        $treeBuilder->getRootNode()
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('hello_world')->end()
            ->end()
        ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

Register the extension when preparing the Kernel, by editing `src/AppKernel.php` (or your kernel location anyway):

```php
<?php

namespace App;

// use ...many classes...

class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    // ...cut..
    protected function prepareContainer(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->registerExtension(new AppExtension());

        parent::prepareContainer($container);
    }
    // ...cut..
}
```

Finally, use your configuration under `config/packages/app.php` (or yaml if you prefer):

```php
<?php

use Symfony\Config\AppConfig;

return static function (AppConfig $config): void {
    $config->helloWorld('!');
};
```

If you are using Symfony < 5.4.25, to making the `config:dump-reference` commands works, instead of registering the extension in the Kernel, implements the extension into the kernel itself. To avoid cluttering the code, best option is to use the decorator pattern. This is the alternative way:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

// use ...many classes...
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\ConfigurationExtensionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\ExtensionInterface;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel implements ExtensionInterface, ConfigurationExtensionInterface
{
    // ...cut..

    /** @var AppExtension Decorated extension */
    private $appExtension;

    public function __construct(string $environment, bool $debug)
    {
        // ...cut...
        $this->appExtension = new AppExtension();
    }

    /** {@see AppExtension::load()} */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        $this->appExtension->load($configs, $container);
    }

    /** {@see AppExtension::getNamespace()} */
    public function getNamespace()
    {
        return $this->appExtension->getNamespace();
    }

    /** {@see AppExtension::getXsdValidationBasePath()} */
    public function getXsdValidationBasePath()
    {
        return $this->appExtension->getXsdValidationBasePath();
    }

    /** {@see AppExtension::getAlias()} */
    public function getAlias()
    {
        return $this->appExtension->getAlias();
    }

    /** {@see AppExtension::getConfiguration()} */
    public function getConfiguration(array $config, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        return $this->appExtension->getConfiguration($config, $container);
    }
    // ...cut..
}
```