# How to separate Symfony (6.x) service and its configuration (using ContainerConfigurator)?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a service (it is not a bundle but might be in the future) which is using complex array as configuration - I would like to create a separate config file for that array in config/packages, let`s say "config/packages/my_service.php".

Example which I think is valid from Documentation (https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#accessing-configuration-parameters) (see below) does not work with error "*You have requested a non-existent service ...*". My service is available via debug:container and works otherwise. Using Symfony 6.1.

I am not sure why this service is not available during config compile time.

```
    <?php
    
    namespace Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\Configurator;
    
    use App\Services\MyService;
    
    return static function(ContainerConfigurator $container) {
        $container->services()->get(MyService::class)
            ->arg('$foo','bar');
    };
```

where 'foo' => 'bar' would be my complex config.

Another way to separate service from configuration is by using *configurator service* which Symfony offers (I have used it in different cases) but I am reluctant because I wanted to have all config under config folder.

Any other ways to do it?

Comment: Try loading the config file as a [Resource](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/resources.html) in your service...

Comment: This is a good idea but it will load external file on every request when the service is used. If I could get ContainerConfigurator to work, it would preload my data in compile time, if I am correct.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this? It's getting away from the purpose of the service in my opinion...

Comment: @vinceAmstoutz - in this particular case service is used in REST API endpoint to provide frontend with menu structure available to end user (based on current role, etc). I might as well store necessary configuration in database and service accessing database would be OK. However, because menu logic is (currently) hardcoded, I figured configuration file would be more appropriate or at least an alternative.

Comment: @Andis, the Yaml parser is fast, it's not an external file (loading from another domain for example), its part of your project on the same system. Yes it will read the file every time it needs too but that's what your server does.. Ps: I do this for my menu structure.

Comment: @Andis I'm still not entirely sure what you are trying to do but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64698404/how-to-load-a-custom-config-file-in-a-bundleless-application-with-treebuilder/64699601#64699601) provides an example of how to basically add an extension and process a config file at the application level.  It makes use of the little known Kernel::prepareConstainer() method.  But I confess I still don't quite understand why you seem to be trying to configure a service using a bundle config file.

Comment: I will probably move this service to some bundle as it will be shared across projects. What other service configuration methods you could recommend? Thanks for example, I will check it out, as I want to learn more about Container in general.

Comment: @Andis Just out of curiosity have you tried creating your service using set instead of get? `$container->services()->set(MyService::class)`? Don't know if it will work as this sort of thing is typically done in an extension or compiler pass.  Might need to exclude MyService from autowire. But maybe.

Comment: @Cerad your solution is curently deprecated. Please see the doc before purpose a solution and explain it ! ;)